# The appropriate way of implementing toggleable features into my code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

*(I'm a beginner)*

What is the recommended/cleanest/most efficient way of implementing features that can be toggled on/off by users?

I'm planning to add some features to my app that the user can toggle on or off in a Settings page. E.g., haptic feedback when tapping certain `View`s. In my code, this `View` has a `onClickListener` that executes the haptic feedback and some other methods. In the Settings page for my app, I'll put something like *"Enable haptic feedback"* with a `Switch`. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLOdS.png)

The first idea that comes to mind is just putting `if` wherever the `vibrate` method is called. Something like...

```
    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {
        if (hapticsSwitch.isEnabled) {
            vibrate(10) //10 ms feedback
        }
    
        //more methods...  
    }
```

However, this `if` would need to be repeated whenever I call any toggleable feature in my app. So perhaps a cleaner way would be putting this `if` inside those features' methods. E.g.

```
    public void vibrate(Long duration) {
        if (hapticsSwitch.isEnabled) {
        // ...
        }
    }
```

But I have no experience with toggleable features. **So, what is the recommended/cleanest/most efficient way of implementing toggleable features into my code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very nice question and its not specific to toggle, but to "single level of abstraction" as uncle  bob calls it.
In my opnion the right thing to do is to put it inside the vibrate function and inside any function that is influenced by that parameter.

There are 2 things you should consider:

1. Does `Vibrate(long duration)` can do its job well without hapsticsSwitch. I think the answer to that is no and it will work well only if its caller did the if statement you suggested, other developer can easily fall in that pit and create a bug
2. How easy it will be to change that logic when this condition will be changed from only looking at `hapsticsSwitch && newFeature`how many changes will you have to make. In my opinion it will be nuch harder to go over all the callers of vibrate.

Final note, I think you might want to use the vibrate without the condition in your app it does not mean you should move the of statement from `vibrate(Long duration)` to its caller, but you need to split your functions to something like `vibrateIfNeeded(Long duration)` and `vibrate(Long duration)` function that vibrate if needed will call.

Tip: read the book called "clean code" by robert c. Martin

Comment: Thank you! For the first item, `vibrate()` gives a vibration (haptic feedback) to the user, `hapticsSwitch` is just the `Switch` that says wether the user wants vibrations or not. Without hapticsSwitch there'd always be a vibration, which wouldn't be very good if the user doesn't want them. On the second item, absolutely. It'd be easier to update if I had 1 check per method definition instead of one check p/ every call. About splitting the method, I think it'd be a good idea to just rename `vibrate` to `vibrateIfNeeded` because splitting just to call `vibrate` looks kind of redundant

Comment: I'll put the check inside the definition of the method then - and probably rename it to doSomething**IfNeeded** or doSomething**IfEnabled** too. And I'll definitely read Clean Code, some people recommended it too. Thank you!

Comment: I just would like to add something, from what I understand now you will need to call `vibrateIfNeeded()` every time you use `View.onClickListener`, so you will duplicate this call a lot instead you can create an abstract class that implements the Click Listener interface and overrides the method onClick making it `final` and exposes another abstract method now internally the check will be done and whenever you wanna call `new View.OnClickListener` just instead call `new MyClassListener`, If the comment is not clear since you said you are a beginner tell me to post an answer with code example.